# italic font in LyX?

Tags: lyx, italic

How does one generate italic font in LyX?  I just want to select some text and click something in the menu system or type a keyboard shortcut to do this.  I have previously found it in the menu system, but it's not in a place that's intuitive for me so I cannot find it quickly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select some text. Then, under the menu *Edit* > *Text Style* > *Customize...* (or right-click *Text Style* > *Customize...*)

[image]

Under *Shape*, select *Italic*:

[image]

This translates to `\textit` from LaTeX's point of view.

---

Alternatively you can *emphasize* an item (translated to LaTeX's `\emph`) by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

Comment: Using emphasis is probably a better idea than specifying italic explicitly. As an alternative to the keyboard shortcut, there is also a toolbar button: it's on the top row, about two thirds of the way across, and looks like a letter A with an exclamation mark over the top.

Answer (score 10):

There is a convoluted menu system for this, but the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>. The 'e' stands for emphasis.

Comment: Best and easiest answer :D